# How to get overflow to work correctly in CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've just started learning CSS grid and have decided to try and build the technical documentation page challenge from FCC: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/NdrKKL

In my implementation, I can get 85% of the way but I'm struggling to get the overflow to work correctly so that both the sidebar and the content can scroll independently. I think it might be a problem with margin somewhere but can't identify where.

When I apply:

```
  overflow: auto;
```

to my content, it cuts off half of my HTML.

Where am I going wrong?

https://codepen.io/braedongough/pen/PVYvzR

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but is your problem that the main body element has a scrollbar?

Comment: see this: [Medium - CSS Grid, maintaining aspect ratio and managing overflow](https://medium.com/compass-true-north/css-grid-maintaining-aspect-ratio-and-managing-overflow-ed54c510782a) @Braedon

Answer (score 1):

For the sidebar, add a `position: fixed;` That is what basically makes the sidebar and content "separate".

For the content, add a `margin-left: 200px;` That number could be anything you want it to be. You need to do that or the sidebar and your content will overlap (because the sidebar has a fixed position).

Remove the `height: 100vh;` from content. It causes it to take up the whole screen and breaks the overflow.

I fixed your codepen for you: https://codepen.io/newracket/full/bzbyxJ